# How to get URL Parameter in Forms for Function Based View (Django)

Tags: django, forms, url, parameters, view

I am trying to get my url parameter value in my form however I am unsure of how to do so. Many answers online that I found from are only for Class Based Views.

This is my path:

```
path('courses/<str:course_abbr>/<str:module_abbr>/<int:year>/<int:semester>/<int:stage>/designations',
     views.designations, name='designations')
```

This is my form which I am trying to get course_abbr into:

```
class DesignationForm(forms.Form):
class Media:
    css = {
        'all': ('admin/css/responsive.css', 'admin/css/base.css', 'admin/css/widgets.css',)
    }
    js = ('/admin/jsi18n',)

module_coordinator = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Staffs.objects.all(),
                                                    widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Module Coordinator",
                                                                                  is_stacked=False),
                                                    required=False,
                                                    label="")
instructor = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Staffs.objects.all(),
                                            widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Instructor",
                                                                          is_stacked=False),
                                            required=False,
                                            label="")
moderator = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Staffs.objects.all(),
                                           widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Moderator",
                                                                         is_stacked=False),
                                           required=False,
                                           label="")
verifier = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Staffs.objects.all(),
                                          widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Verifier",
                                                                        is_stacked=False),
                                          required=False,
                                          label="")
invigilator = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Staffs.objects.all(),
                                             widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("invigilator",
                                                                           is_stacked=False),
                                             required=False,
                                             label="")
```

Comment: These are passed as the `*args` and `**kwargs`. So in your function you can communicate these accordingly to your form.

Comment: Real sorry but could I have an example?

Comment: Plenty of examples in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request). In your case the function will get keyword arguments with these keywords: `module_abbr, year, semester, stage`.

Comment: Hi @CoffeeBasedLifeForm, I tried to do this:


    `def designations(request, course_abbr, module_abbr, year, semester, stage):
       mc_form = ModuleCoordinatorForm(course_abbr, module_abbr, year, 
    semester, stage)
        template_name = 'curricula/designations.html'`

However, only stage is giving this error: 
"int object is not iterable"

Update: I just realized stage isn't the one that's giving the error. It seems that when all the keyword arguments are present, the error will be shown

Comment: Please post the full error traceback and the view function.